# Get object from array with NSDictionary objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I need to be able to display an object value no matter what the key is. Or display an object with the objects key.

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"key"];
    [array addObject:dict];

    NSLog(@"Key: %@", [[array objectAtIndex:0] key]);
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:[[array objectAtIndex:0] key]]);

    //Both logs "[__NSDictionaryM key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
```

Why doesn't this work? And how should I do it?

NOTE: In this example the `keyValue` is "key", BUT I don't know the `keyValue`in the original code..

Comment: `[[array objectAtIndex:0] ObjectForKey:@"key"];`

Comment: `[[array objectAtIndex:0]allKeys];` it will return NSArray with all keys of that dictionary.

Comment: what is `key`? has it been defined in a custom category, maybe?

Comment: The question has been answered, and I don't understand your question @holex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableDictionary *dict= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"key"];
[array addObject:dict];
```

Try

```
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *values = [dict allValues];
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
```

and log by

```
NSLog(@"Keys: %@", keys);
NSLog(@"Values: %@", values);
```

also

```
for (id key in keys) {

    NSLog(@"Value: %@ for Key: %@", [dict objectForKey:key], key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
for(NSDictionary *aDict in array)
    {
        for(NSString *aStrKey in aDict)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [aDict valueForKey:aStrKey]);
        }
    }
```